# Forcing UIAlertView into landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview, cgaffinetransform

I need to display a UIAlertView in landscape mode. I tried the obvious, setting the transform in the `willPresentAlertView:` delegate method to no avail:

```
-(void) willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {

    alertView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried in the `didPresentAlertView`?

```
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    // UIAlertView in landscape mode
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
    alertView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(alertView.transform, 3.14159/2);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: This might work in the `willPresentAlertView`, but I've not tried it before.

Comment: It does work on didPresentAlertView:, but it has undesired effect of showing the view in the wrong position first.

Comment: Does it work in `willPresentAlertView`? That will probably remove the animation effect if so.

Comment: I Think it may be a bug with `willPresentAlertView`, seems to default back to portrait. Could try this code without the animations, `alertView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(alertView.transform, 3.14159/2);` inside `didPresentAlertView`

Comment: Replacing 3.14159/2 with the built in constant M_PI_2 makes it look a little nicer.

Answer (score 1):

It should rotate automatically if you're using `UIViewController`.
Did you forget to return `YES` for the desired orientations in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES; /* auto rotate always */
}
```

Comment: No, I'm returning YES, but it doesn't autorotate. :-(

Comment: It should. If it's deep in a hierarchy of controllers, all of them should have auto-rotate enabled. Also, having 2 or more controllers at window level may lead to problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

What is the orientation of the view that shows the alert? I had the same problem, I tried to show an UIAlertView inside a landscape view but always appeared in portrait orientation. So, I forced the orientation of the status bar:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:theOrientation];
```

That worked to me.

Answer (score 1):

Before the Alert Window appeared , Set the current window display at the top. If not do this ,you can see the alert window's rotate animate.

```
-(void) willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {

    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

    self.view.window.windowLevel = 2003;

}
```

Rotate the Alert Window

```
-(void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{

    UIWindow * alertWindow = alertView.window;
    alertWindow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
    alertWindow.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT,SCREEN_WIDTH);
    alertWindow.center = CGPointMake(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(showLandscapeAlertView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
```

After the Alert window rotated, move the current window back.

```
-(void)showLandscapeAlertView {

    self.view.window.windowLevel = 0;

    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];

}
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with quite the same issue lately. For me solution was using `UIAlertController` - cover older handling of `UIAlertview` and `UIActionsheet`.

1. Create new controller, which is dedicated from `UIAlertController`, where you must overloaded methods `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`, like in example bellow.

**AlertViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AlertViewController : UIAlertController 

@end
```

**AlertViewController.m**

```
#import "AlertViewController.h"

@interface AlertViewController ()

@end

@implementation AlertViewController

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.view setHidden:YES];
}

...
```

2. implement method for showing alert view where you needed.

   - (void) showInfoAlertView {

     ```
         AlertViewController *alert = [AlertViewController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert" message:@"This is an alert." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

         UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
         [alert addAction:ok];
         [self presentViewController:alert animated:NO completion:nil];
     }
     ```