# How to transform UIAlertView in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uialertview, cgaffinetransform

I have an portrait application, using image controller to take picture but I give an instruction to user to take picture in the landscape right , which works perfectly but when the photo is not proper according to my application , it gives a alert to take another picture correctly, here UIAlertView comes in portrait orientation , which is looking completely abnormal , so I tried to transform my UIAlertView  which is not working , find bellow to see my code to transform the `UIAlertView`

```
 alertView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

this application am running in iOS 7

Comment: Is your app is configured to run only as portrait?  I suspect if the app was allowed to run landscape then your UIAlertView would rotate automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to forge rotation by transform do on Window of AlertView.

```
alertView.window.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved this with using `UIAlertController` look at my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38590962/5763297

**EDIT:**

this solution is only for iOS 8 and higher, because component UIAlertController is available from this version of iOS

Comment: UIAlertController is only available for iOS 8 and later. The question is relating to iOS 7, which would use UIAlertView

Comment: @JimTierney yes, you are right. I should be more specific in my answer that the solution is only for iOS 8 and higher. I placed it here because the question was directly what I was looking for, so I bum into it, but the answer which I found here was not quite enough for me. The share of iOS version bellow version 8 is about 3%, so I thought I can help others, who are or will be struggling with the same problem.